# Taylor expansion for a Bessel function with complex argument

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, bessel-functions, perturbation-theory

If we have a Bessel function of the first kind and the $m$-th order as $J_{m}(x+i\epsilon x)$, where $m$ is integer, $x, \epsilon$ are real and $\epsilon$ is a small parameter ($0<\epsilon\ll 1$), can we expand this in Taylor series and write

$$ J_{m}(x+i\epsilon x) \approx J_{m}(x)+i\epsilon x J^{'}_{m}(x)-\frac{(\epsilon x)^{2}}{2}J^{''}_{m}(x)+\cdots \ \ \ ?$$

I just want to double check if this is a correctly written Taylor expansion, since the coefficients here contain $x$?

Comment: This is fine.  Fix $x$, then take the Taylor series with respect to the variable $\epsilon$ at $\epsilon = 0$.  In fact, $J_m$ is an entire function, so your series converges to $J_m(x+i\epsilon x)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for confirming it